# Angular Format-date com a data diminuida um dia

Tags: angularjs, data, angularjs-directives

Estou usando um diretiva do angular para tratar as datas

minha diretiva é esta :

```
app.directive("formatDate", function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, modelCtrl) {
            modelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(modelValue) {
                if (modelValue){
                    return new Date(modelValue);
                }
                else {
                    return null;
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Quando eu exibo a data da minha listagem vem a data correta. Mas quando eu abro o modal para edição dos dados a data vem com um dia a menos.

Vejamos;

Minha listagem está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na listagem eu formato a data desta forma :

```
<td>{{pes.dataNascimento | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
```

Mas quando eu clico no modal para alterar a pessoa selecionada a data é carregada com um dia a menos ficando assim :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

meu componente está desta forma:

```
<div class="es col-md-4">

                    <label class="lb" style="margin-top: -5px;">Data Nascimento <label class="lb1"
                      data-toggle="tooltip" title="ÁREA DE TEXTO OBRIGATÓRIO"> *</label>
                    </label> <input  title="ÁREA DE TEXTO OBRIGATÓRIO"  style="margin-top: -70px;"
                      required="required" class="form-control "  name="data" id="data" type="date" ng-model="pessoa.dataNascimento" format-date/>

                  </div>
```

Não sei se é relevante mas ao clicar em alterar os dados captados da listagem estão assim :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que poderia estar ocorrendo ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é problema de timezone.
Você pode usar o ng-options para resolver desta maneira:

```
ng-model-options="{timezone: 'UTC'}"
```

Ou ainda assim:

```
ng-model-options="{timezone: timezone}"
```

E no controller:

```
$scope.timezone = ((date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60) * -100)
```

Link do [fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/YuBKgwj13fkHwtA7cfUc?p=preview) com o exemplo

Comment: Existe alguma maneira de deixar isso global?